# Getting a specific types of HTML form elements only --> JUST input type button

Tags: javascript, html, element

I used the following code to disable just the button, whether it is input type=submit, input type=button, or button tag from a form that I created. But I realize that my code collects all elements in my form, whether it is text or buttons or radio buttons or checkbox and so on. This takes up resources.

Is there a cheaper way to perform what I need such as getElementByTagName(), but now for getElementByTypeName? I want to find the most resource efficient possible way.

UPDATE: I tried not to document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]') code because I want to limit my selection to the current form where the clicked button currently placed. For multi form page this will get all the input type button from all forms. I prefer similar function like form.getElementByTagName.

Thank you

This is my original javascript:

```js
/** For disabling all elements in any form. */
function preventMultiClicksOld(formParent)
{
  var elements = formParent.elements;
  for(var e=0; e<elements.length; e++)
  {
   if(elements[e].type=="submit" || elements[e].type=="button" || elements[e].tagName=="button")
   { elements[e].disabled=true; }
  }
}

/** For disabling all elements in any form and then submit. */
function preventMultiClicksNSubmit(formParent)
{
  var begin = new Date().getTime();
  this.preventMultiClicksOld(formParent);          
  formParent.submit();
  alert("Form is being submitted. Please hold and do not click or perform anything else!");
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  alert("Time: " + (end-begin));
}
```

The following is what I want to do for the preventMultiCliks function:

```js
    /** For disabling all elements in any form. */
    function preventMultiClicks(formParent)
    {
      //Disable input type submit
      var elements = formParent.getElementByTypeName("submit");
      for(var e=0; e<elements.length; e++)
      { elements[e].disabled=true; }
      
      //Disable input type button
      var elements = formParent.getElementByTypeName("button");
      for(var e=0; e<elements.length; e++)
      { elements[e].disabled=true; }
      
      //Disabling the button tag buttons only
      elements = formParent.getElementsByTagName("button");
      for(var e=0; e<elements.length; e++)
      { elements[e].disabled=true; }
    }
```

And this is my sample HTML:

```html
<form name="myform" action="test.html" method="GET">
<button type="button" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);">Tag Button with document submit</button><br>
<input type="button" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Button with document submit"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit regular"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit dengan return true"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit dengan document submit"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00001" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00002" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00003" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00004" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00005" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00006" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00007" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00008" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00009" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00010" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00011" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00012" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00013" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00014" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00015" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00016" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00017" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00018" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00019" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00020" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00021" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00022" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00023" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00024" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00025" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00026" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00027" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00028" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00029" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00030" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00031" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00032" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00033" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00034" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00035" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00036" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00037" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00038" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00039" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00040" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00041" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00042" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00043" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00044" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00045" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00046" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00047" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00048" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00049" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00050" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00051" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00052" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00053" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00054" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00055" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00056" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00057" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00058" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00059" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00060" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00061" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00062" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00063" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00064" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00065" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00066" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00067" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00068" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00069" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00070" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00071" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00072" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00073" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00074" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00075" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00076" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00077" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00078" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00079" value="Hahahaha"><br>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')`

Comment: I tried not to use that code because I want to limit my selection to the current form. For multi form page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used multiple selector as the function argument to `querySelectorAll()`

**EDIT:** Expanding on [Andrew Li](/users/5647260/andrew-li)'s comment

```js
var elements = document.forms["myform"].querySelectorAll('button[type="button"],input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]');
for(var i = 0 ;i < elements.length; ++i){
  elements[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" action="test.html" method="GET">
<button type="button" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);">Tag Button with document submit</button><br>
<input type="button" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Button with document submit"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit regular"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit dengan return true"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="preventMultiClicksNSubmit(this.form);" value="Tipe Submit dengan document submit"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00001" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00002" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00003" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00004" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00005" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00006" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00007" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00008" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00009" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00010" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00011" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00012" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00013" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00014" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00015" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00016" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00017" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00018" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00019" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00020" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00021" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00022" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00023" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00024" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00025" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00026" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00027" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00028" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00029" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00030" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00031" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00032" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00033" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00034" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00035" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00036" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00037" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00038" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00039" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00040" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00041" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00042" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00043" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00044" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00045" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00046" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00047" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00048" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00049" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00050" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00051" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00052" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00053" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00054" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00055" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00056" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00057" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00058" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00059" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00060" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00061" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00062" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00063" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00064" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00065" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00066" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00067" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00068" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00069" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00070" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00071" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00072" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00073" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00074" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00075" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00076" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00077" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00078" value="Hahahaha"><br>
<input type="text" name="mytext00079" value="Hahahaha"><br>
```

Comment: Tested your code and loving it. Thank you. This is awesome.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JQuery like this

```
var input = $('<input>');
$(input).attr('type',field['type']);
$(input).attr('name',field['name']);
$(input).val(field['value']);
$(input).addClass('form-control');
```

You even can select the name of the input, or search part of the name with selector:

```
$("input[name^='mytext00']")
```

This way you can select all input which name started with 'mytext00'.

If you are dealing with dynamic DOM element, use:

```
$(document).on("click","input",function(){
    $(this).select();
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. For a start `jquery` was not requested. Furthermore, the jquery you have provided does not demonstrate selecting the elements (buttons) that the question is referring to.

Comment: I tried to avoid JScript if possible and avoid adding js libs. Trying to K.I.S.S it.